# Find element inside an iframe (external domain)

Tags: jquery, iframe

Is there any way to access elements loaded inside an iframe?

I'm trying this but doesn't seem to work:

```
if($('#cboxLoadedContent iframe').contents().find('#customer-login')[0] ){ ... }
```

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate. I'll look if I find a good original question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked, I hd opened the file locally (`file://`) whereas the content was loaded with `http://` protocol.

Answer (score 1):

If the content of the iframe is provided by another domain, the only way you can see its content from your page is that this content is given with appropriate [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

This is a protection scheme known as [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Note that there is also the solution to let the browser see only one domain, by using a proxy.